# Pcolormesh in 1D

Tags: matplotlib

please have a look at the following issue.

Why is this working:

```
y=[1,2]; x= [0,1,2,3]
z = [6, 2, 3, 5, 2, 4, 4, 5]
z = np.reshape(z, (2, 4))
plt.pcolormesh(x, y, z)
```

But this is **not**:

```
y=[1]; x= [0,1,2,3]
z = [6, 2, 3, 5]
z = np.reshape(z, (1, 4))
plt.pcolormesh(x, y, z)
```

Or in other words, how can I use "pcolormesh" for a 1D array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pcolormesh` is expecting `x` and `y` to be the *boundaries* of the mesh.  So, there should be one `x` value and one `y` value more to set the necessary boundaries. You'll need `2` `y` boundaries and `5` `x` boundaries for a `1` by `4` mesh.

When working with 2D meshes, `pcolormesh` also allows `x` and `y` to indicate the *center* of the mesh. This is your first example. Note, matplotlib calculates boundaries in between the given values, which is quite noticeable when the `x` or the `y` values aren't equidistant.  If only one y value is given, matplotlib doesn't have a simple way to calculate in between boundaries.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 5))
y = [1, 2]
x = [0, 1, 2, 3]
z = [6, 2, 3, 5, 2, 4, 4, 5]
z = np.reshape(z, (2, 4))
ax1.pcolormesh(x, y, z)

y = [1, 2]
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
z = [6, 2, 3, 5]
z = np.reshape(z, (1, 4))
ax2.pcolormesh(x, y, z)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: 1d pcolormesh]